# K8S Provide kubeconfig as bytearray genericclioptions

Tags: azure, go, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Is there any way to pass to `&genericclioptions` of k8s client a `bytearray` of the kubeconfig?

https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/cli-runtime/pkg/genericclioptions

Currently, the  `genericclioptionsits` is taking it by default from the env/path to the file, but I need to pass it explicitly as `bytearray` as a parameter and not a ref to a file or from the env, is there a way to do it?

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "github.com/spf13/pflag"
    "k8s.io/cli-runtime/pkg/genericclioptions"
)

func main() {
    kubeconfigData := []byte("my_kubeconfig")

    // create a new flag set and bind the kubeconfig flag
    flags := pflag.NewFlagSet("default", pflag.ExitOnError)
    kubeconfigFlag := flags.String("kubeconfig", "", "absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    flags.Parse([]string{})

    // set the kubeconfig flag to the data in the byte array
    *kubeconfigFlag = "-"
    configOverrides := &genericclioptions.ConfigOverrides{ClusterDefaults: genericclioptions.NewClusterDefaults()}
    configLoader := genericclioptions.NewConfigFlags(false).WithOverrideFlags(configOverrides)
    configLoader.KubeConfig = bytes.NewBuffer(kubeconfigData)

    // ...
}
```

Any idea?

**SECOND TR**Y
**I tried also the following version** and I got error: error loading config file , any idea?

```
func main() {
    // read the kubeconfig file into a byte array
    kubeconfig, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./kubeconfig--pln.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // create a ConfigFlags object with the kubeconfig byte array
    flags := genericclioptions.NewConfigFlags(false)
    *flags.KubeConfig = string(kubeconfig)
    dc, err := flags.ToDiscoveryClient()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(dc)

    res, err := dc.ServerPreferredNamespacedResources()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(res)
    }

    // use the flags object to create a clientset or other Kubernetes API object
    // ...
}
```

Comment: nstead of the byte array. To pass the kubeconfig as a byte array, you need to set the KubeConfig field of the ConfigLoader to a bytes.Buffer created from the byte array.

Comment: @Sourav - can you please provide an example?

Comment: `package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "github.com/spf13/pflag"
    "k8s.io/cli-runtime/pkg/genericclioptions"
)

func main() {
    kubeconfigData := []byte("my_kubeconfig")

    configOverrides := &genericclioptions.ConfigOverrides{ClusterDefaults: genericclioptions.NewClusterDefaults()}
    configLoader := genericclioptions.NewConfigFlags(false).WithOverrideFlags(configOverrides)
    configLoader.KubeConfig = bytes.NewBuffer(kubeconfigData)

    // ...
}`

Comment: @Sourav - can you please write it as answer ?as it very hard to understand it like this... ( I mean the code)

Comment: I have posted the answer as per your statement. Kindly let me know, if it works else I will delete the answer. @Jenney

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is trying to set the kubeconfig flag to a string value of "-" instead of the byte array. To pass the kubeconfig as a byte array, you need to set the KubeConfig field of the ConfigLoader to a bytes.Buffer created from the byte array.

Here's an updated version of the code:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "github.com/spf13/pflag"
    "k8s.io/cli-runtime/pkg/genericclioptions"
)

func main() {
    kubeconfigData := []byte("my_kubeconfig")

    configOverrides := &genericclioptions.ConfigOverrides{ClusterDefaults: genericclioptions.NewClusterDefaults()}
    configLoader := genericclioptions.NewConfigFlags(false).WithOverrideFlags(configOverrides)
    configLoader.KubeConfig = bytes.NewBuffer(kubeconfigData)

    // ...
}
```

Try the above code once, also u can follow these [link1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/aks/azure-csi-blob-storage-provision.md) [Link2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-arc/kubernetes/tutorial-use-gitops-connected-cluster.md) [Link3](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-arc/kubernetes/tutorial-akv-secrets-provider.md) [Link4](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/aks/open-service-mesh-deploy-addon-bicep.md)

Comment: HI, thanks. the code doesnt compile, does it works for you? I got error on `&genericclioptions.ConfigOverrides{ClusterDefaults: genericclioptions.NewClusterDefaults()` there is no ConfigOverrides for the genericclioptions , any idea?

Comment: Hey @Jenney, allow me some time to check and comeback on this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the config is used, one option might be to bypass the config loader step entirely.

For example:

```golang
func getClientCmdConfig() (*clientcmdapi.Config, error) {
   kubeconfigData := []byte("my_kubeconfig")
   var cfg clientcmdapi.Config
   if err := json.Unmarshal(kubeconfigData, &cfg); err != nil {
      return nil, err
   }
   return &cfg, nil
}

func useClientCmdConfig() (..., error) {
   cfg, err := getClientCmdConfig()
   if err != nil {
      return ..., err
   }
   
   clientCfg, err := genericclioptions.NewDefaultClientConfig
   if err != nil {
      return ..., err
   }

   // ... do something with clientCfg
}
```

Comment: HI, thanks, this is not working...is it working for you ? can you please provide the full example ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain more of what you are doing? What is the config being used to do?

Comment: I jsut want to use genericclioptions but provide the kubeconfig explicit not from the env or path to kubeconfig, anything like this working will be very helpful...